# How to change terminal emulatior keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Is there a way to change command-line shortcuts such as copy and paste from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> respectively?

I often accidently use the default system shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> instead of those defined for command-line use, which I find very annoying, so I was wondering...

**Is it possible to change the keyboard shortcuts of the terminal emulator?**

Comment: With gnome-terminal?

Comment: @hg8 Ubuntu terminal, which is the gnome terminal - so yes :)

Comment: Personally I'd discourage doing that; remapping CTRL+V deprives you of the ability of sending a Synchronous idle character (maybe you won't miss that) but remapping CTRL+C deprives you of the ability of SIGINTing the foreground process in case things get out of control. It takes a bit, but you'll get used to the difference eventually.

Comment: FYI you aren't changing "command line" shortcuts but the terminal emulator's shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnome-terminal`.

Go in **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Shortcuts**.

Then simply edit them :

[image]

Comment: oh right.. lol **=)**

Comment: This answer seems incompete. For one thing how do you remap the interrupt (kill) action that was originaly CTRL-C. (Also is there any way to remap all default key combinations, the preferences hardly list any.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the key or keys to be pressed for a keyboard shortcut:

1. Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select **System
   Settings**.
2. Open **Keyboard** and select the **Shortcuts** tab.
3. Select a category in the left pane, and the row for the desired
   action on the right. The current shortcut definition will change to
   **New accelerator…**
4. Hold down the desired key combination, or press **Backspace** to clear.

Comment: Please note that those settings apply system-wide, but not on the `gnome-terminal`. It uses its own custom shortcuts, not those set up by the system. I think your answer is wrong.