# Running a custom command from the Terminal icon in the dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-dock

I'd like to execute the command:

```bsh
gnome-terminal --geometry=80x50+0+0
```

when I left-click on the Terminal icon in the Ubuntu dock (on Ubuntu 18.04).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/704648/how-to-change-command-line-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could simply change the default settings in you `gnome-terminal` profile, or
2. You could create a new launcher item, based on the current `gnome-terminal.desktop` file.

   This file is located at `/usr/local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`. Copy it to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the `Exec=` and `Name=` lines accordingly and add it to your dock. I would suggest to use a different file name when copying the original `gnome-terminal.desktop` file.

Comment: The new launcher works but when I add it to the dock the left-click on the icon keeps open the terminal with the old setting (position and geometry).

Comment: In your newly created `.desktop` file, have you added the line `Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=80x50+0+0`?

Comment: Yes, i did. When I launch it from "Show applications" it works fine.

Comment: I get this: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`
`['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'emacs25.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'keepassxc_keepassxc.desktop', 'shutter.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop']`

Comment: But it does not work, when you add this newly created shortcut to the dock? Just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, It does not work from the dock when I add it to the favourites.

Comment: I can try to replicate this once I have access to an Ubuntu installation with a graphical environment for testing.

Comment: @Gabriele From the output it seems the launcher that is pinned to the dock is the `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` one, *not* the `gnome-terminal.desktop` one. So try doing the same as the answer suggests with the `/usr/local/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` file too.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Use a different dock or add it to favorites manually `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'emacs25.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'keepassxc_keepassxc.desktop', 'shutter.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop']"` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Simply just edit the preferences of the terminal. 
Go to Edit --> Preferences and then change the number of rows to 50 as in the pic below.

[image]

Comment: I need to put the window in a defined position, not just resize it.