# How to change terminal emulator keyboard shortcuts from cli?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I know how to change terminal shortcuts using GUI as it is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704648/how-to-change-terminal-emulatior-keyboard-shortcuts)

However, how to do so from cli?

I want to use Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v for copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keybindings of Gnome Terminal are stored as dconf settings, and thus can be changed with the `gsettings` command, e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ copy "'<Control>c'"
```